# How to make sure that only the bottom most element in UI hierarchy responds to tap?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I've a situation in a windows phone project wherein I'm dynamically creating UI elements one inside the other. This can lead to say a 10 StackPanel hierarchy . Now each UI element has a tap event attached to it. How do I make sure that only the tap event associated with the bottom most element is triggered (my problem being all 10 events are triggered)?

Comment: Have you tried to use eventArgs.Handled = true; into your event handlers to stop the event propagation? It could stop the event at the first event handler receiving it, which will be the one associated with the deepest StackPanel located where the Tap has occured.

Comment: @AirL post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to use `eventArgs.Handled = true;` into your event handlers to stop the event propagation? (see in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747183.aspx#When_to_Mark_Events_as_Handled)).

It will stop the event propagation at the first event handler receiving it, which will be (in your case) the one associated with the deepest `StackPanel` located where the [Tap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.uielement.tap%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) event occurs.